# Nvidia broken after BIOS Reset

Tags: nvidia, uefi, bios

After resetting my BIOS, my nvidia drivers are disabled and Ubuntu reverts to non-proprietary graphics drivers. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue for me when I reset BIOS was UEFI Secure Boot was enabled. Disabling this allowed nvidia proprietary drivers to work.